# How to turn dataframe into pair count in R?

Tags: r, sna

I am new to R and I am doing a final assignment for the class. I have encountered with some issues for tidying up the data. 
For instance, I have this dataframe as follows.

```
StudentId table_wk1 table_wk2 table_wk3
0034       1           1          2
0067       1           1          1
0098       1           2          2
0079       2           2          1
```

What I want to achieve is to turn this dataframe into following array. Whenever the two students choose the same table, there would be one count between them, so it would be like:

```
0034  0067  2
0034  0098  2
0034  0079  0
0067  0098  1
0067  0079  1
0098  0079  1
```

Thank you! Please tell me if my question lacks clarity. This is my first question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, then the count will be on when the `table_wk` values between the two student IDs are the same.

The code below basically creates a new dataframe for the combination of student IDs (you can also use `gtools` or `combinat` package for this), then calculates the result based on comparison of the two combination's side.

```
# Generate data
df <- data.frame(StudentId = c("0034", "0067", "0098", "0079"),
                 table_wk1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
                 table_wk2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                 table_wk3 = c(2, 1, 2, 1),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Process data
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(df$StudentId, 2)), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2.1 <- merge(df2[-2], df, by.x = 'V1', by.y = 'StudentId', sort = F)
df2.2 <- merge(df2[-1], df, by.x = 'V2', by.y = 'StudentId', sort = F)
df2.2 <- df2.2[match(df2$V2, df2.2$V2),]  # Solve the sorting issue due to merge

# Create result
df2$Result <- rowSums(df2.1[-1] == df2.2[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

First create all possible combinations of students

```
df$StudentId = as.character(df$StudentId) 
df_new=data.frame(t(combn(df$StudendId,2)))

> df_new
    X1   X2
 1 0034 0067
 2 0034 0098
 3 0034 0079
 4 0067 0098
 5 0067 0079
 6 0098 0079
```

Now, use the apply function and loop through each row in df_new matching the 2 studentIDs with the corresponding rows in df and figuring out in which columns the two rows are equal.

```
 df_new$Value_Count = apply(df_new,1, function(x) sum(df[df$StudendId == x[1],2:4] == df[df$StudendId == x[2],2:4]))


> df_new
   X1   X2   Value_Count
 1 0034 0067           2
 2 0034 0098           2
 3 0034 0079           0
 4 0067 0098           1
 5 0067 0079           1
 6 0098 0079           1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps my question!